# Does the "HID" signify that a wireless keyboard is operational as well as a hard wired keyboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard

My keyboard is wireless but doesn't work (I'm having to use the touch screen keyboard).I have performed all the troubleshooting suggested and it still doesn't work. Per the device screen the "HID keyboard" is working. Does the "HID" represent wireless as well as hard wired keyboards? Plz help!

Comment: While I have answered your question, I have specifically ansered the only question contained within the body of your question, in other words I specify what HID actually represents.  You have not actually provided enough information to identify the reason your keyboard does not currently work.  I assume you have changed the batteries on the keyboard?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of Device Manager, with the sections `Keyboards`, `Human Interface Devices` and `Other devices` (might not be present) all expanded? Might help to finding why your wireless keyboard doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the "HID" represent wireless as well as hard wired keyboards?

HID has nothing to do with your keyboard being a wireless or wired USB device.  HID stands for Human Interface Devices.

Source: [Introduction to HID Concepts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/introduction-to-hid-concepts)

Comment: The only reason the article link exists, is to provide context to what HID is exactly, which is well beyond the scope of the question.  It isn't necssary to quote the article, the contents of the article beyond it indicating what HID stands for, isn't necessarily relevant to the question.  It is provided to inform the author about HID.

Answer (score 1):

Some Bluetooth devices may implement two operating modes by configuration:
An embedded mode and a Bluetooth mode.

Embedded mode allows connecting to the device without having to do the pairing process,
while Bluetooth mode requires pairing. In embedded mode the keyboard will act as a
wired device that is available earlier to Windows.
On some computers, this is essential for using the Bluetooth keyboard for entering
the BIOS.

Switching the operating mode can in some cases be done in the Device Manager,
in Properties of the device, where the *Advanced* tab may present an
"HID Device" check-box.
There can never be any guarantee of the effects of such a change, negative or positive,
on the usability of the device.

For the problem of the device not working, try the methods listed
in the article
[Fix: Bluetooth keyboard connected but not working in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-bluetooth-keyboard-connected-not-working/).